# samba: sharing multiple directories in one user's directory with multiple people

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, network-shares, samba

I am the sysadmin of an ubuntu 14.04 linux machine in my home. I have an encfs directory mounted at /home/me/Encfs . I would like to share various parts of this directory with various members of my family. As an example -- perhaps I'd like to share /home/me/Encfs/family with my wife, and /home/me/Encfs/family/jr (which my wife will have access to) with my son. I'd like them to have read/write access to everything in the directory which I'm sharing with them. I don't want anyone to be able to access anything outside of the directory which I'm sharing with them.

Is this possible? Do I need to set up some complex group system whereby me, my wife and my son are in one group which has rw access to /home/me/Encfs/family/jr and then me and my wife only are in another group which has rw access to /home/me/Encfs/family ? And if I want to share another directory elsewhere with just my son I'd need to set up another group with just me and him in? Is this the way things are supposed to be set up? Or am I missing a trick?

Comment: Do the various members of their family use each their own computer? Do they share a computer? Do they use the Ubuntu machine? How do identify they themselves to the computers they use?

Comment: They don't use the Ubuntu machine, they typically use Windows or Chrome OS. Each device that connects to the samba shares is used by precisely one person (me or another member of my family). I can set up various samba shares in various names -- this was what I was envisaging -- each member of my family should have a samba login and password, so the issue is then giving these logins the right permissions (including the right permissions on files and directories that I want more than one of them to access) without having to jump through a lot of stupid group hoops.

Comment: On looking at https://superuser.com/questions/1064225/samba-create-subdirectory-shares-with-their-own-permissions?rq=1 I see that perhaps this really is the answer -- for every directory perhaps I just have to create a group which contains all the users that I want to be able to access that directory. I was just a bit surprised about this because for N users in general one might need 2^N groups. Given that N=5 in my situation, this isn't too bad...

Comment: You can try to use access control lists (ACL, e.g. `man setfacl`), but I'm not sure if they work together with Samba.